# partitioned index on a non partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, clustered-index, database-partitioning

How to create a partitioned index on a table which is not partitioned although there is a partition function and scheme available. It is an exercise I read somewhere, not a real problem

```
create partition function func(datetime)
as range right for values
('20040601', '20050601')
go
create partition scheme scheme1
as partition func
to ('primary')
go

create table student
(
studentid int not null primary key nonclustered,
firstname varchar(30) not null,
date datetime not null
)
```

i was thinking of

```
create clustered index IX_StudentID_Date
on student(studentid, date)
```

but the table is not partitioned, so how to create the index, without partitioning the table?

Comment: Note that in the process you will create what is called a non-aligned index (index is partitioned differently from table) which will cause several problems (performance, inability to use SWITCH operations etc). You said this is an exercise, but in production be very careful not to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you partition the "table" you are actually partitioning the clustered index. So partitioning a non clustered index is actually the same as partitioning a "table"

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_StudentID_Date 
        ON student(studentid, date) 
        ON scheme1(date)
```

you just have to make sure that the partition field is part of the index.